# Meaning of ~つもりではいる in that sentence

Tags: usage, meaning

I don't understand  the meaning of ~つもりではいる in this sentence :

> そしていちおう手加減してやるつもり**ではいる**が殺されてしまっても負けとなる。
>
> And, although I'm planning on going easy on you, you will also lose if you happen to get killed.

I'm familiar with the ~つもり+である construction and I remember reading somewhere that でいる could sometimes replace である (not sure about that).

So is it でいる + は (and what difference is there between である、でいる and ではいる)?

Or is it で (て forme of だ) + 入る and in that case, what does はいる mean in that context?

Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's a combination of で＋いる with the contrastive は inserted.  No, it's not で入る.

When you use 〜でいる instead of 〜だ・である, the emphasis is on the *current* state (or with 〜でいた, a *past* state).  In your translation, that's reflected with the English present progressive "planning on".

In this particular example, the particle は is added to show contrast with the following clause.